# What would the British name of a 1073741824th note be?

Tags: rhythm

The wikipedia page for a 256th note (demisemihemidemisemiquaver) talks about a 1073741824th note. This note seems to only be supported by the LilyPond software.

I'm guessing that since such a note is never used, and wasn't established alongside the other notes with the same name, there isn't a British name for it. However, if there is, what is it? I'm not sure of the naming convention for these notes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually, I just found out. Looking at the naming for the other notes, you add semi then hemi then demi. Since that note is 2^30, we can just copy-paste hemidemisemi 9 times (including the first quaver level). Doing this, we get the glorious:

```
hemidemisemihemidemisemihemidemisemihemidemisemihemidemisemihemidemisemihemidemisemihemidemisemihemidemisemiquaver
```

> (Thanks to user1079505 and Divizna for correcting the name, I put 10
> hemidemisemis the first time)

Comment: Wouldn't that be a 8589934592nd note? Note, that quaver is an eighth note, not a whole note.

Comment: Yep, it's "hemidemisemi" *nine* times, so hemidemisemihemidemisemihemidemisemihemidemisemihemidemisemihemidemisemihemidemisemihemidemisemihemidemisemiquaver, not hemidemisemihemidemisemihemidemisemihemidemisemihemidemisemihemidemisemihemidemisemihemidemisemihemidemisemihemidemisemiquaver.

Comment: Just call it a grace note & be done with it ;)

Comment: Or we can call it a billion-seventy-three-million-seven-hundred-forty-one-thousand-eight-hundred-twenty-fourth note, what's wrong with that?

Comment: @Divizna "billion" will be confusing in countries using long scale https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Long_and_short_scales

Comment: @user1079505 Don't worry about that, we don't speak English. I'm all for calling it "miliardsedmdesáttřimilionsedmsetčtyřicetjednatisícosmsetčtyřiadvacetinová nota" but I'm afraid you'd have trouble pronouncing the ř that comes up three times there.

Comment: I've always just called it "Steve".

Comment: @Divizna would we more trouble with these ř's than we do with Dvořak?

Comment: @phoog Depends, if you pronounce his name as "Dvorak" you're doing it wrong. If you pronounce it like they show at [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anton%C3%ADn_Dvo%C5%99%C3%A1k) then the sound in "čtyři" is the same, in "tři" it's its nonvoiced twin. (Btw I can't resist telling you it's spelled Dvořák, to denote that the second syllable is long.) So if you can say Dvořák then you'd only stumble on "tisíc" and "dvacetina" which contain the ť sound that's also foreign to English. (It's not written that way but ti is always pronounced as ťi in domestic words.)

Comment: @Divizna - seems like a pain in the rs to me...

Comment: @Tim No no, not rs, it's ř. One consonant, not a cluster of two. :o)) Like when you say řiť. That's what we call the body part you mentioned. (Not a swearword. It's the correct term. We do have a less polite word too of course but here's not the place for extended linguistic discussions.)

Comment: @Divizna - I have a wind-up computer, that doesn't have that accent. Only a joke - perhaps a wind-up..? Things get quite tedious on this site - no-one seems to have a sense of humour!

Comment: @Tim  Ah, don't get wound up, or you'll wound me.

Comment: @Divizna: In German, this part of the body is called "Ař". ;-)